# Run UserControl code in backcolorchanged event C#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, backcolor

i want to execute a piece of code when a labels backcolor is changed..

following is the code

```
private void lbl_ps_BackColorChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lbl_ps.BackColor == Color.Green)
       {
            menu_ctrl.setup_array = str_array;
            indx = 0;
        }
    }
```

here 'menu_ctrl' is a usercontrol where this setup_array consists of following code

```
public string[] setup_array
    {
        get
        {
            return list_array;
        }

        set
        {
            list_array = value;
            setup_list(value);
        }
    }

private void setup_list(string[] list_item)
    {
        //this.Width = 266;
        this.Height = 181;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            this.Controls.Remove(labels[i]);
        }
        label1.Visible = false;
        this.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        indx_abs = 0; indx_rel = 0;
        n = list_item.Length;

        Array.Resize(ref labels, n);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            labels[i] = new CustomText();
            labels[i].Left = 20;
            labels[i].Top = ((30) * i)+1;
            labels[i].IsSelected = false;
            this.Controls.Add(labels[i]);
            labels[i].Text = list_item[i];
        }

        labels[indx_abs].IsSelected = true;
    }
```

but the code wont execute....it works fine if i call this code from a button click event.. but it wont execute in backcolorchange event

any help?

EDIT:i tried break point and i got this error in the first for loop in setup_list function

```
Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'CustomText' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
```

the error was caught deep inside a reference dll i've been using. btw a function in this dll is raising this colorchanged event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @Nati Dobkin!!

i was able to identify the the code trigger was being created on a new thread.. and found this on the internet to force run a code in main thread.

```
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => 
           { 
                //run your code here
           }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically your code is correct, it worked fine for me. What i would check is 2 things

1) The event is actually attached, search your code for

this.lbl_ps.BackColorChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.lbl_ps_BackColorChanged);

2) That the event is being raised, somewhere in your code you have to be

lbl_ps.BackColor = Color.Green; // or any other color.

Comment: i know it works!!! but not fully if  i remove "menu_ctrl.setup_array = str_array;" and write a label text change code it works but not this usercontrol code... i dont know wat to do it shows no error whatsoever.. it just dont work

Comment: Have you put some break points on the code? on what line does it stop executing?

Comment: thanks for that.. i tried break point and i got this error in the first for loop in setup_list function

`Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'CustomText' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.`

the error was caught deep inside a reference dll i've been using. btw a function in this dll is raising this colorchanged event

Comment: Glade you where able to find the solution, just was about to write you about this. Another point here, you can use AnyControl.InvokeRequired to indemnify if you need to use the Invoke method